# I need to get the tabs working using chico-ui framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I can't seem to make the tabs to work.. I have to use [this](http://chico-ui.com.ar/):

I'm doing what the documenation says but I'm not sure if I'm using the right html markup / jquery...

Here's the [API](http://chico.mercadolibre.com/ui/api/ch.Tabs.html)

This is what I have:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  var tabs = $("#tabs").Tabs();
  
     });
```

```css
/**
 * Tab Navigator
 */
.ch-tabs {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.ch-tabs .ch-tabs-triggers {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ch-tabs .ch-tabs-triggers li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Triggers */
.ch-tab {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #333 !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.ch-tab:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.ch-tab:active {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Trigger ON */
.ch-tabs .ch-tab.ch-expandable-trigger-on,
.ch-tabs .ch-tab.ch-expandable-trigger-on:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0f0f0, #fff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f0f0f0, #fff);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.lt-ie10 .ch-tabs .ch-tab.ch-expandable-trigger-on,
.lt-ie10 .ch-tabs .ch-tab.ch-expandable-trigger-on:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f0f0f0', endColorstr='#fff');
}

/* Container */
.ch-tabs .ch-box-lite {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div id="tabs">
            <ul role="tablist" class="ch-tabs">
                <li><a href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1">Tab1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/static/ajax.html#ajax">Ajax</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div role="presentation">
                <div id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet purus in sapien luctus sodales. Curabitur dui velit, cursus in sagittis aliquam, dictum at neque. Ut gravida scelerisque lorem non pulvinar. Pellentesque et urna vitae nisl porta imperdiet sed nec ipsum. Sed non sem velit. Cras id consectetur tellus.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab2">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet purus in sapien luctus sodales. Curabitur dui velit, cursus in sagittis aliquam, dictum at neque. Ut gravida scelerisque lorem non pulvinar.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```